# Creation Date of Outlook/Exchange Calendar Event

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, exchange, exchange-2010

Is it possible to get the creation date (or last modified date) of an event in Outlook Calendar? I'm running Outlook 2013 (but the event is created with Outlook 2010) against Exchange Server 2010.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In Outlook 2010 or Outlook 2007 you can change the calendar view to list, Then add columns that will show different fields,  To do, once in the list view, go to View settings, in advanced view settings select columns,  There a number of field types to chose from, find the one that has "Created", "modified" and you might also want to find "changed by",  These additional fields in the list view will give you the informaiton you want.

Answer (score 6):

In 2013: Click on "VIEW", Choose "Change View" and choose "list"
On the top left corner of the data, right click on the icon that looks like a sheet of paper.
Choose "View Settings"
Sellect "Columns..."
Then add the colums you wish to view in your list of data.
Change the dropdown under "Select available columns from:" to "All Appointment fields"
Add the columns you wish to have shown by left clicking on your choice and then click Add to move it to the left. I added "Created" and "Modified" to my columns.
Don't forget to click Okay and Okay.
The columns should now be in your list view data. 
I hope this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Just found out that in OWA there's a "Sent: [date]" in the top right corner.

Answer (score 0):

List view is not very easy to navigate with a lot of entries, and I found the  option below works better.  **However, as an Exchange administrator** when I open a meeting I see the last modified date and time in the status bar, but I don't understand why it's not showing for others.  If anyone has any ideas on this please let me know.

Open an item (appointment in this case) - go to its **File**, **Options**, **Customize Ribbon**. Select "**All Commands**" at the top. Click in the list below and type P on the keyboard (to jump to the Ps) then find **Properties**. There will be 3 "properties" - you want the **middle one** (plain old "Properties"). You will have to Create a **New Group** on the **Appointment** menu, **rename it to Properties** and **Add Properties** to this group. This will now sow the Properties icon for each appointment. Clicking Properties will show the last Modified date and time.